# While loop doesn't work inside a function JS

Tags: javascript

I built a color guessing game using javascript.
The loop doesn't work in case of being inside the function do_game. If I get it outside the do_game it worked, but just the first if in the check_guess works for all option. Please help me fix this.

```
    var chosen;
var userInputText;
var finished = false;
var guesses = 0;
var colors = ["aqua", "azure", "beige", "brown", "chocolate", "coral", "crismon", "gold", "lime", "linen", "snow", "tomato"];
/*  
  One way to set the background color of a web page is
  myBody=document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
  myBody.style.background=name_of_color;*/
function do_game() {
    "use strict";
    chosen = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
    while(!finished) {
        userInputText = prompt("I am thinking of one of these colors: \n\n aqua, azure, beige, brown, chocolate, coral, crismon, gold, lime, linen, snow, tomato\n\nWhat color am I thinking of?");
        guesses += 1;
        finished = check_guess();
    };
}

function check_guess() {
    "use strict";
    var idx = colors.indexOf(userInputText);
    if(idx === -1) {
        alert("Sorry, I don't recognize your color\n\n" + "Please try again.");
        return false;
    }
    if(userInputText > chosen) {
        alert("Sorry, your guess is not correct!\n\n" + "Hint: your color is alphabitcally higher than mine.\n\n" + "Please try again.");
        return false;
    }
    if(userInputText < chosen) {
        alert("Sorry, your guess is not correct!\n\n" + "Hint: your color is alphabitcally lower than mine.\n\n" + "Please try again.\n\n");
        return false;
    }if (userInputText === chosen) {
        alert("Congratulations! You have guesses the color!" + "It took you " + guesses + " to finish the game!" + "You can see the colour in the background");
        return true;
    }
```

}

Comment: You are not resetting value of `guesses`

Comment: try this `guesses +=1` or `guesses++`

Comment: It still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Guesses value is not being updated here

```
guesses = +1;
```

replace this by either

```
guesses += 1
```

or

```
guesses++
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem here is the global finished variable. Once it is set to true by check_guess() after  calling once, it will prevent the loop from running later. Just put it inside the  do_game() function.

```
function do_game() {
    "use strict";
    var finished = false;

    chosen = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];

    while(!finished) {
        userInputText = prompt("I am thinking of one of these colors: \n\n aqua, azure, beige, brown, chocolate, coral, crismon, gold, lime, linen, snow, tomato\n\nWhat color am I thinking of?");
        guesses += 1;
        finished = check_guess();
    };
}
```